# Orange exclamation mark on smartgit

Tags: git, smartgit

I am not sure that I understand the orange exclamation mark on SmartGit as below, please could someone explain a little bit what does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The orange exclamation point shows pending merge requests on the branch from your remote repository. If you hover over the orange exclamation point it will show "Pending merge requests: Bitbucket", or whatever remote repository you use such as GitHub. I tested this by merging or declining inbound merge requests. Once nothing was left pending, the exclamation point went away.

There is a general reference to this functionality in the release notes (you may need to scroll down to find your version):

[Smartgit - Whats New](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/whatsnew)

Specifically from there for Version 7:

> **BitBucket and Atlassian Stash**
>
> BitBucket and Atlassian Stash are now supported with pull requests and comments, similar to GitHub.

There is also all the new features and bug fixes in the changelog found here:

[Smartgit Changelog](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/changelog.txt)

Comment: Good catch. +1. I reference your answer in mine for more visibility.